# Reading three inputs from the user using Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, console.readline

Is this the correct way to do it, since I'm new to C#

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter m,y,n: \n");
double month, year, numberOfMonths = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: in this way only numberOfMonths will be assigned. month and Year will not be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by asking user to enter the values split-ed by some delimiter like space, semi colon etc. And then split the value and parse accordingly. for example

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] split = input.Split(',');
double month = Double.Parse(split[0]);
double year = Double.Parse(split[1]);
double numberofmonth = Double.Parse(split[2]);
```

Ofcourse the above code is not the most elegant/efficient/error free code. But, it is just written to get the idea across.

Comment: getting on error on this line
string[] split = input.Split(" ");

the split is not highlighted

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     double month;
     double year;
     double numberOfMonths;
     Console.WriteLine("please enter m \n");
     month=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("please enter y \n");
     year=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("please enter n \n");
     numberOfMonths=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store input in an array and tell the user to press enter after every input and then doing this:

```
string[] input=new string[3];
Console.WriteLine("please enter m,y,n: \n");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  input[i]=Console.ReadLine();
```

then you can convert the string input to whatever datatype you want,
the above is not a very efficient way, but you can use it to get large number of input from user and its easy when all the input have the same datatype.