# Read matrix elements in row wise

Tags: c#, matrix

I am writing C# program for a matrix.when I enter matrix inputs from console, each element is coming in the separate row.But, I want to read row elements in a single line.

This is my code

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the matrix");
            int n= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[ , ] matrix=new int[n,n];
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    matrix[i,j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                   // Console.Write("\t");
                }

            }
```

present I am getting like

1

2

3

4

But, I want like

1      2

3      4

Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read one row in one line, you can ask user to enter space-separated values like `1 2`, `3 4` and read like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the matrix size");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
//add size and other validation if required
int[,] matrix = new int[n, n];
Console.WriteLine("Enter your values separated by space.");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var values = (Console.ReadLine().Split(' '));
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(values[j]);
    }
}

//to write 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: @N123 It's customary to accept answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the entire line and do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(t => int.Parse(t)).ToArray();
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
          matrix[i, j] = input[j];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the matrix");
            int n= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[ , ] matrix=new int[n,n];
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] elements = line.Split(' ');

                for(int j=0; j<n || j < elements.Length; j++){
                    matrix[i,j]=Convert.ToInt32(elements[j]);
                }    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619573/reading-three-inputs-from-the-user-using-console-readline)

In your situation :

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < n; j + 2){
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] split = input.Split(' ');
        int firstNumber = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
        int secondNumber = Int32.Parse(split[1]);
        matrix[i,j] = firstNumber ;
        matrix[i,(j+1)] = secondNumber ;
       }
   }
```